# Best way to maintain daywise interval partitions in 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

I had created a sql script in 11g that would drop all partitions having high value less than 60 days in all partitioned tables in the database

```
DECLARE
   TNAME      VARCHAR2 (300);
   PNAME      VARCHAR2 (300);
   HIGHVAL    VARCHAR2 (3000);
   POSITION   SMALLINT;
   VAL        LONG;

   CURSOR C1
   IS
      SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, PARTITION_POSITION, HIGH_VALUE
        FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%$%'
         AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN%';
BEGIN
   OPEN C1;

   LOOP
      FETCH C1
       INTO TNAME, PNAME, POSITION, VAL;

      HIGHVAL := VAL;
      EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;

      IF TO_DATE (SUBSTR (HIGHVAL, 10, 11), 'RRRR-MM-DD') <
                                                          TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                                                          - 60
      THEN
         IF POSITION = 1
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ALTER TABLE ' || TNAME
                                  || ' SET INTERVAL();'
                                 );
         END IF;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (   'ALTER TABLE '
                               || TNAME
                               || ' DROP PARTITION '
                               || PNAME
                               || ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES PARALLEL 2;'||CHR(10)
                               || '--DROPPED'
                               || '--'
                               || TO_DATE (SUBSTR (HIGHVAL, 10, 11),
                                           'RRRR-MM-DD'
                                          )
                              );

         IF POSITION = 1
         THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
                                (   'ALTER TABLE '
                                 || TNAME
                                 || ' SET INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,''DAY''));'
                                );
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;

   CLOSE C1;
END;
/
```

I'm executing the generated SQL text

Kindly advice if this correct and any room for enhancement???

Comment: Your script doesn't _do_ anything; it prints some code... what do you think the problem is with your code? Is there anything wrong? Is it not doing what you expected?

Comment: I'm executing the generated SQL text.  Just want to know if what im doing is right, or may be any better way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

- It's a perfect place for implicit cursor, so you don't need to manually declare variables, fetch, open & close, ...
- Filter high value in the query, earlier is better
- Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to apply changes instead of manually executing whatever gets printed
- You don't need to commit, since it's all DDL

The code:

```
BEGIN
  FOR p IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, PARTITION_POSITION, HIGH_VALUE
            FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%$%'
            AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN%'
            AND TO_DATE (SUBSTR (HIGH_VALUE, 10, 11), 'RRRR-MM-DD') < TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 60)
  LOOP
    IF p.PARTITION_POSITION = 1
    THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p.TABLE_NAME || ' SET INTERVAL()';
    END IF;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p.TABLE_NAME
                   || 'DROP PARTITION ' || p.PARTITION_NAME
                   || ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES PARALLEL 2';

    IF p.PARTITION_POSITION = 1
    THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p.TABLE_NAME
                     || ' SET INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,''DAY''));';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And a few warnings:

- <del>Watch out for UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES, it does not work with IOT tables (if you use them)</del> *(I was wrong with this one)*
- Watch out for resetting/setting intervals. The general rule is that you can't drop last non-interval partition. Guessing this would be position 1 is risky. Better to rely on user_tab_partitions.interval flag.